Performing Code Coverage on a .NET Core Project Using a Java Automation Project with TestNG
Using a Java automation project, I'm trying to perform code coverage on a dotnet project.
It worked when I did it on Windows OS, using dotnet-cover.
The steps are:

dotnet-coverage collect -id test1 -f cobertura "dotnet run"
Wait until the run is completed successfully.
Run some tests from TestNG (It runs locally).
Shut it down: dotnet-coverage shutdown test1
Generate the report, run reportgenerator.exe -reports:"output.cobertura.xml" -targetdir:"coveragereport" -reporttypes:Html


The problem is that I'm trying to do the same on macOS, M1 chipset(arm64), and it doesn't work.

I tried to reproduce that process with no success. When I shut down, I get the following message:

No code coverage data available. The profiler was not initialized.

I decided to try another way after hours I spent to find a solution.
So, I tried the dotCover command line (JetBrains).
dotnet-dotcover cover \
  --output="/Users/username/repos/CodeCoverage/output.coverage" \
  --TargetExecutable="/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet" \
  --TargetArguments="exec /Users/username/repos/CodeCoverage/bin/Debug/net8.0/CodeCoverage.dll" \
  --WorkingDir="/Users/username/repos/CodeCoverage"

It doesn't work for me.
In the bottom line, this is what I'm trying to do:

Launch the .NET Core application.
Run TestNG Automation.
Shut down the .NET application after the tests are finished.
Generate a Coverage Report.

Any ideas?

Did you check to see if there is a compatibility issue with using Arm? It could potentially be an issue with different hardware architecture.
